# How to get the all values from two tables based on phone number

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

Here i have two tables, i want get the results from this two tables.i tried lot but i am unable to get the exact results can you please any help me, i am using this application in codeiniter.

First Table

> new_staff

```
staff_id              firstName        Mobile          userType

  1                  Soupranjali       9986125566       Teacher
  2                  Sujata            8553880306       Teacher
```

Second Table

> new_student

```
student_id           first_Name        fatherMobile        user_type

  1                  janarthan         8553880306         Student
  2                  Santanu           8277904354         Student
  3                  Sarvan            8553880306         Student
```

here **8553880306**  both table this mobile number is present, so want get to the both table results

> Expected Results

```
    {
  "status": "Success",
  "Profile": [
    {
      "staff_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Sujata",
      "userType" : "Teacher"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "firstName": "janarthan",
      "user_type" : "Student"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "3",
      "firstName": "Sarvan",
      "user_type" : "Student"
    }
  ]
}
```

So tried like this but i unable to get the answer, so please anyone help me,

> my model

```
 public function android_memberList($mobile)
    {
        $this->db->select('new_staff.staff_id, new_staff.firstName, new_staff.userType, new_student.student_id, new_student.first_Name, new_student.user_type');
        $this->db->from('new_staff');
        $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
        $result = $query->result_array(); 
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

**Based on my query it is returning the out put like this, but this is not my expected json fomat**

```
 [
  {
    "staff_id": "2",
    "firstName": "Sujata",
    "userType": "Teacher",
    "student_id": "1",
    "first_Name": "janarthan",
    "user_type": "Student"
  },
  {
    "staff_id": "2",
    "firstName": "Sujata",
    "userType": "Teacher",
    "student_id": "2",
    "first_Name": "Santanu",
    "user_type": "Student"
  }
]
```

> updated answer

```
 {
  "status": "Success",
  "Profile": [
    {
      "staff_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Sujata",
      "userType": "Teacher"
    },
    {
      "staff_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Sujata",
      "userType": "Teacher"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "first_Name": "janarthan",
      "user_type": "Student"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "2",
      "first_Name": "Santanu",
      "user_type": "Student"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can not get dynamic column names in output.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile','left');
```

Please replace this line in your code and check, I think it's working and that you'd get the data as you want.

Comment: Hi , i tried your code , [
  {
    "staff_id": "2",
    "firstName": "Sujata",
    "userType": "Teacher",
    "student_id": "1",
    "first_Name": "janarthan",
    "user_type": "Student"
  },
  {
    "staff_id": "2",
    "firstName": "Sujata",
    "userType": "Teacher",
    "student_id": "2",
    "first_Name": "Santanu",
    "user_type": "Student"
  },
  {
    "staff_id": "1",
    "firstName": "Soupranjali",
    "userType": "Teacher",
    "student_id": null,
    "first_Name": null,
    "user_type": null
  }
]

Comment: Please check this response this not a correct response

Comment: Check my expected results

Comment: $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile','union');  Please try this one if after that Line it's not get correct answer then may be it's other problem.☺

Answer (score 1):

You are using MySQL `join` to merge data from 2 tables, which will never get you the desired result. You can use `union` to merge data from both the tables.In your case, the problem is your field names are different in both the tables.

**Solution 1:**

In SQL generalize the column names using `alias`, the problem is in your `json` array, you will get generalize keys.

**Solution 2:**

Run 2 different queries, get data in 2 different arrays, merge 2 arrays and get the desired result. I am implementing the 2nd solution here.

```
public function android_memberList($mobile)
{
    $this->db->select('distinct(new_staff.staff_id), new_staff.firstName, new_staff.userType');
    $this->db->from('new_staff');
    $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
    $query1 = $this->db->get();

    # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
    $result_new_staff = $query1->result_array(); 

    $this->db->select('distinctnew_student.student_id), new_student.first_Name, new_student.user_type');
    $this->db->from('new_staff');
    $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
    $query2 = $this->db->get();

    # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
    $result_new_student = $query2->result_array(); 

    $final_result=array_merge($result_new_staff,$result_new_student);

    $result["status"] = "Success";
    $result["Profile"] = $final_result;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Mr @Bikram Pahi, i tried code , it is working little bit fine , here staff_id and firstName is comming two time should not come like this, please see my updated answer

Comment: staff id and firstName coming on dublicate

Comment: could you please post the output?

Comment: I tried your second solution, please see my updated answer in my post,

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to get two table data with one key left join is best option for this

You can try like this

```
$this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile','left');
```

Comment: How is your answer different that the one from kishan ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query in your codeigniter project which will give you all columns with new names.
Or you can modify column names with your compatibility.

```
$this->db->select('ns1.student_id, ns1.first_name as student_first_name'); 
$this->db->select('ns1.fatherMobile, ns1.user_type as student_user_type');
$this->db->select('ns2.firstName as staff_first_name');
$this->db->select('ns2.Mobile as staff_mobile, ns2.userType as staff_user_type');
$this->db->from('new_student as ns1');
$this->db->join('new_staff as ns2', 'ns2.Mobile = ns1.fatherMobile', 'left');
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

You can see your query solved here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0288bef1b4f753a134000ae73d6bd58d